# a question for arbitrary union of compact sets

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Is the  "if arbitrary union of compact sets is compact then the topological space is finite or the union is finite" proposition correct? If it is correct then how can we prove it?

Comment: The statement is unclear. If $X$ is infinite then you basically say "if arbitrary union is compact then the union is finite" which is hard for me to understand. Did you mean "if $X$ is an infinite space then there is an infinite collection of compact subsets such that their union is not compact"? Also you should probably assume that "compact" means at least "T1 compact" since any space with finite number of open subsets is a counterexample.

Comment: @freakish I wanted to say that $(X,\mathcal{T})$ is a topological space, the family $\{K_i\}_{i\in I}$ is a family of compact sets in the space $X$. If $\bigcup_{i\in I} K_i$ is compact then $X$ is finite or $I$ is finite.

Answer (score 1):

Any infinite  space in the cofinite topology has the property that all of its subsets are compact and so the union of compact subsets is automatically compact too.

Note that this space is just $T_1$, if $X$ were Hausdorff (or even just KC) then “any union of compact subsets is compact” implies that $X$ is finite and discrete.

Comment: Ohh. I see. This space has escaped my notice. Thank you very much.